# Why vim always stuck?

Tags: vim

Recently, when I use vim to edit cpp file, it stucks frequently when I do "save" command.

When I use `ps aux |grep vim`  I find the following line.

```
haoli    21143  1.2  0.1 217916 22212 pts/3    D+   13:07   0:05 vim xxx.cc
```

`D` means `Disk sleep`.  And when I run `kill -9 21143`, the process still exists.
Is vim stuck when saving to disk?

Who cause this bug?

1. Vim-plugin.
   Here is my plugin list

```
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'connorholyday/vim-snazzy'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'terryma/vim-multiple-cursors'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive
Plugin 'wincent/command-t'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plugin 'octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight'
```

2. Disk
   I don't know how to debug.

Comment: Better suited for [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can't kill process in D state, AFAIK. Are you editing files on a network file system?

Comment: No, it is in local file system.@RuslanOsmanov